# How to find out if a search string is in a few columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstTable] as A
JOIN [SecondTable] as B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE (NOT B.column1 LIKE '%'+ A.someCol + '%')
AND (NOT B.column2 LIKE '%'+ A.someCol + '%')
```

I had the "NOT" next to the "LIKE" and that didn't work either.  Also I want to be sure to be case insensitive is this right?  I am looking for  all the documents from A that the value A.someCol doesn't appear anywhere in B.column1 or B.column2

For example

```
A.someCol 'substr'
B.column1 'test'
B.column2 'test2'
```

The above should return the row with those values.

```
A.someCol 'substr'
B.column1 'test'
B.column2 'testsubstrtest'
```

The above should not return the row with those values.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It might surprise you, but a non-working query is not a very good explanation.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired outcomes.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: Now it's even less clear. The title says one thing, the sample data says another thing, and above all, if we want to test ourselves we have to write the DDL and DML for the sample data. Please [edit] your question to provide proper sample data and desired results.

Comment: Noted, the below answer is what I was looking for but I will add DDL and DML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) to solve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstTable] as A
JOIN [SecondTable] as B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column1) = 0 
    AND CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column2) = 0
```

You can also specify to search [case-sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql#d-performing-a-case-sensitive-search) or [case-insensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql#e-performing-a-case-insensitive-search):

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstTable] as A
JOIN [SecondTable] as B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) = 0 
    AND CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) = 0
```

---

**How does it deal with NULLs?**

> If either *expressionToFind* or *expressionToSearch* is NULL, `CHARINDEX` returns NULL.

In this case you can use one of the following solutions, using [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql):

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstTable] as A
JOIN [SecondTable] as B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE ISNULL(CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column1), 0) = 0 
    AND ISNULL(CHARINDEX(A.someCol, B.column2), 0) = 0
```

or...

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstTable] as A
JOIN [SecondTable] as B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE CHARINDEX(ISNULL(A.someCol, ''), ISNULL(B.column1, '')) = 0 
    AND CHARINDEX(ISNULL(A.someCol, ''), ISNULL(B.column2, '')) = 0
```

Comment: Actually, one problem, how does it deal with NULLs?